# Cloud Firestore rule for Read - on the basis of where clause

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have one collection `PINTesting` that contains 6 digit code sent to mail, I want to verify if user enter that 6 digits correctly.

so I want to have rule that can allow the read only and only if `PinCode` is provided in `where` clause.  So user can't pull the record without PIN match, Your help is really appreciated.  I tried to get the data from resource, but could not make it working.  :(

```
match /PINTesting/{userId} {      
  allow write: if true
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId && WHAT_SHOULD_HAVE_HERE
}
```

data and collection structured as :

```
PINTesting(collection)  >  userId(Doc Id)   > {PinCode,  Email} (Document)
```

Query going to look like -

```
this.$db
  .collection("PINTesting")
  .where("PinCode", "==", "123456")
  .where("Email", "==", "abc@domain.com")
  .get()
  .then((snap) => console.log('Pin Verified', snap.docs.length === 1));
```

Comment: How about adding a uid property to PINTesting?  Allow the read if `request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid`

Comment: actually I want to verify the PIN, so I want something like if PIN provided by user does match with pin already saved in `collection`, mean for owner of the `doc` also, he has to provide the pin first.  Lets call it another security layer?